# How to use Doctrine OracleSessionInit listener with Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am using oracle and I am recieving this error:

> Could not convert database value "17-NOV-11 12.17.33 AM" to Doctrine Type datetime. Expected format: Y-m-d H:i:s

Also I can´t create new rows because oracle complaints about the datetime format.

I know that mysql datetime format and oracle one are different.

I understand that you can use doctrine listeners with symfony 2:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

And, there´s a doctrine listener created to fix this issue:

Doctrine/DBAL/Event/Listeners/OracleSessionInit.php

The question is how Exactly your turn it on in symfony 2.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me so much time!!! Note: this seems to work also with Symfony 3

Answer (score 17):

Well It appears I will answer myself this time.

You have to add it as a service using the event tag.

```
app/config/config.yml 

services:
    my.listener:
        class: Doctrine\DBAL\Event\Listeners\OracleSessionInit 
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postConnect }
```

my.listener is an arbitrary name for the listener.

Answer (score 10):

In my case Oracle was a second connection (stored under **oracle** key).
The application also used PostgreSQL (stored under **default** key).

The problem was that Listener was executed on the **default** database (PostgreSQL).
So I changed code to:

```
services:
    my.oracle.listener:
        class: Doctrine\DBAL\Event\Listeners\OracleSessionInit
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postConnect, connection: oracle }
```

And all works fine!

Answer (score -2):

I think this link will help you :

Connecting to Oracle with Symfony2 and Doctrine 2.

1. Map Oracle's DATE type to Doctrine's "date" type instead of "datetime" for Oracle driver
2. Properly configures Doctrine to use most common Oracle Date and DateTime environment configurations. You may or may not need this. Check your Oracle server configuration

https://gist.github.com/johnkary/6481664#file-oracledoctrinetypemappinglistener-php

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being *barely more than a link to an external site* is a [possible reason for your answer to be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).