# symfony2 doctrine postConnect event never triggered

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to use doctrine with an oracle 10g database in a symfony2 project.

Everything is working fine but when I try to insert a row with a date column in a table I get the following error :

> [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1850 OCIStmtExecute:
>   ORA-01850: ORA-01850: hour must be between 0 and 23 
>   (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:148)

According to [How to use Doctrine OracleSessionInit listener with Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168161/how-to-use-doctrine-oraclesessioninit-listener-with-symfony2) this error can be fixed by adding the Doctrine\DBAL\Event\Listeners\OracleSessionInit class to the Event Manager in Doctrine.

```
app/config/config.yml 

services:
    my.listener:
        class: Doctrine\DBAL\Event\Listeners\OracleSessionInit 
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postConnect }
```

I tried this solution but it didn't work for me. So I manually added the listener to the eventManager in doctrine thgough my controller :

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        $product= new Product();
        $product->setCreationDate(new \DateTime());
        $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection()->getEventManager()->addEventSubscriber($this->get('my.listener'));
        $em->persist($product);
        $em->flush();
        return array();
    }
```

This is working but this is not really elegant and I don't want to do that with all my controllers...

So my listener seems to be working properly. In my opinion, either the postConnect event is never triggered, or my config.yml is wrong and the listener is not properly set.

Some help would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Debug around [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/DependencyInjection/CompilerPass/RegisterEventListenersAndSubscribersPass.php#L65) to see that event listener is listed or not. I am guessing it is related to default connection parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you m2mdas. I was able to debug the event manager with your advice and I figured out that my listener was not listed. So I checked my config.yml again and it turned out that it was not well formed (2 blank characters were lacking) .

Anyway, everything is ok now, thank you very much for your help.